# WordPress: Include page template dynamically foreach $pages

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, dynamic, include

I'm working on a one-page-wp-site, using each page created as a new slide/section of the content. I wanted different templates for different slides, and had a problem including each template dynamically, but finally figured it out how to do it.

original php:

```
<?php 
    $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
        $page_ID = $page_data->ID;
        $template = get_current_template();

?>  
<section id="<?php echo $slug ?>" class="slide cf">                     
        <?php include($template) ?>

</section>  
<?php 
    } /*end foreach*/
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `include` or `require_once` inside of a template is not the *WordPress Way*.  (For more on why, see [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-include-and-require-files-and-templates-in-wordpress--wp-26419)) WordPress has exposed specific functions for this for a reason - use [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

Note that with this function, templates can be located where they should be - in the theme folder.  With include, you're not going to load them from the proper location (include will load from the root folder, where `index.php` is located, unless the `$template` variable has the full path, which would get messy and be hard to maintain).

```
<?php 
    $pages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
        $page_ID = $page_data->ID;
        $template = get_page_template_slug( $page_ID );
?>  
        <section id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" class="slide cf">                     
            <?php get_template_part($template); ?>
        </section>  
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for enlighting me on this, I was obviously including from the root in my project so it worked well, but I see why this is preferable. :)

Comment: Wierd, tried your sollution, but the `get_template_part` isn't working for me.

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working".  Does it throw an error? Or just not load the template?  At this point, I'd need to know the value in `$template`, and the name (and location) of your template file to help further.

Comment: So I tried putting my templates in a subfolder. The value of `$template` is `subfolder/page-template.php` it works when I use `include` but not `get_template_part`...

Comment: Remove the `.php` from your template.  If you look at the `get_template_part` code, you'll see that it adds it always / automatically on it's own: `$templates[] = "{$slug}.php";` (taht's from the WP function)

Comment: You could do it in your code: `get_template_part(str_ireplace('.php', '', $template))`

Comment: Ok, I still don't really get why the `include` is a bad way, since it worked even when putting it in a subfolder of the theme-folder. What are the pitfalls of this method? *No animosity, only trying to learn more about WP ^__^*

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-include-and-require-files-and-templates-in-wordpress--wp-26419

Answer (score 0):

New php:

```
<?php 
    $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
        $page_ID = $page_data->ID;
        $template = get_page_template_slug( $page_ID );

?>  
<section id="<?php echo $slug ?>" class="slide cf">                     
        <?php include($template) ?>

</section>  
<?php 
    } /*end foreach*/
?>
```

Comment: No, this is not the "WordPress Way".  Don't do it like this! Use [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) instead on `include`!